# Converting Android soft keyboard to Bengali

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I am trying to convert my android softkeyboard to Bengali or any (other language). I have implemented a code for softkeyboard from android developer site. Is it required to set another IME options for conversion for that softkeyboard to any other language? Please give me some advice to do this conversion.

Comment: Please provide some snippet what you have tried, so that we can get a broad idea...

Answer (score 3):

Your question doesn't briefly explain what you really want. I recently developed a Bangla SoftKeyboard which looks like:
[image]

Is that what you want? If so, make keyboard xml layout for Bangla characters(like
qwerty.xml) and in the onKey function of SoftKeyboard.java file commit bangla characters according to their primaryCode(corresponding android:codes in xml file). Feel free to specify where are you getting problem and what you exactly want.

Answer (score 0):

I am sharing a full sample code for tamil language. i have also created this kind of softkeyboard.

Downloadable at https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tamil.visai&hl=en

[Source at github](https://github.com/thamizha/android-tamilvisai)